# virtualbox - guest OS Manjaro - how to automount shared folder

Tags: linux, virtualbox, shared-folders, manjaro

I have a virtualbox set up on my Windows 10 machine.
Also I have the guest additions installed.

I have install a Guest OS Linux - Manjaro XFCE Edition (17.0.2).

I want to auto-mount the shared folder.

How to do it? It seems the normal methods in found on search did not work.
Or should it be done by a script to be loaded at start?

Can someone help?

PS: I am a beginner in Linux

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this VirtualBox guide. [link](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders).

Answer (score 4):

**In host OS:**

Setup shared folder like this: (replace  with your username)

[image: Like this]

**In guest OS:**

Add:

```
mount -t vboxsf <Name of shared folder> <Path to where you want to find the folder>
```

to /etc/init.d/boot.local

Example:

```
mount -t vboxsf Shared_Folder /home/<username>/Shared_Folder/
```

Answer (score 0):

since you say that you tried the classic way of adding a shared-folder ( i suppose you mean through Settings -> Shared Folder )

can you please share your Folders List that you have setup at the Settings -> Shared Folders ?

Open your Manjaro VM, at the top you will see the VM options, go to Settings -> Shared Folders.